# .htaccess rewrite regex: match anything but the other rules must be not affected

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this `.htaccess` I want when I enter `exemple.com/home` it will open file `home.php` and login same thing else it will open `hani.php`

```
RewriteRule ^home$  home.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login$  login.php [L]
...
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)$  hani.php?link=$1 [L]
```

***My problem*** When I go home or any other it will open hani.php

> Please I want a good solution because I have many pages

Comment: add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before last rule

Comment: Or `RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$  hani.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your last rewrite is unconditional and is rewriting **after** other rewrites before that have finished thus sending everything to `hani.php`.

There are 2 solutions (use any one):

1. Exclude all files and directories from last rule using:

```sh
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ hani.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```

2. Exclude dot from your matching patter in last rule so that `home.php` or any request containing dot doesn't match the pattern:

```sh
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ hani.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please note that there is no need to escape `/` in regex patter in `mod_rewrite`.